# Service's data into nested view on load with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On the homepage of an Angular app, I have a view and a nested view (see ui-router code below). For the view, I make an `$http` call to my database and display results using `ng-repeat`. Simultaneously I push those results to a service. In the nested view, I call a single result from the service and display it (I am using two controllers). My problem is that I need all of this to happen on load. Is a "resolve" in ui-router the best way to approach this?

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/open');
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/open', '/open/mainbook');
  $stateProvider
  .state('open', {
  url: '/open',
  templateUrl: 'ang/views/open.html',
})

 .state('open.mainbook', {
  url: '/{featId}',
  templateUrl: 'ang/views/open.mainBook.html',
  })`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not use the service, to combine the two controllers into one, and to call the nested view right away from within the initial `$http` call using `$state.go` (I also give the nested view data within the same call), i.e.
`$scope.featCall = function () {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'true',
      url: '/featList'
    }).then(function (result) {
      $scope.single = [];
      $scope.single = result.data[0];
      $state.go('open.mainbook', {
        featId: $scope.single.id
      });
       bookData.clearProduct();
       angular.forEach(result.data, function (eachOne) {
        $scope.featList.push(eachOne);
        bookData.addProduct(eachOne);
      })
    })
  };`

Note that I still use the service (`bookData`) for later changes to the nested view, just not for the initial population of its data.